# How to use withColumn Spark Dataframe scala with while

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

This is my function apply rule, the col mdp_codcat,mdp_idregl, usedRef changechanges according to the data in  array bRef.

```
    def withMdpCodcat(bRef: Broadcast[Array[RefRglSDC]])(dataFrame: DataFrame):DataFrame ={var matchRule = false
    var i = 0
    while (i < bRef.value.size && !matchRule) {
      if ((bRef.value(i).sensop.isEmpty || bRef.value(i).sensop.equals(col("signe")))
        && (bRef.value(i).cdopcz.isEmpty || Lib.matchCdopcz(strTail(col("cdopcz")).toString(), bRef.value(i).cdopcz))
        && (bRef.value(i).libope.isEmpty || Lib.matchRule(col("lib_ope").toString(), bRef.value(i).libope))
        && (bRef.value(i).qualib.isEmpty || Lib.matchRule(col("qualif_lib_ope").toString(), bRef.value(i).qualib))) {
        matchRule = true
        dataFrame.withColumn("mdp_codcat", lit(bRef.value(i).codcat))
        dataFrame.withColumn("mdp_idregl", lit(bRef.value(i).idregl))
        dataFrame.withColumn("usedRef", lit("SDC"))
      }else{
        dataFrame.withColumn("mdp_codcat", lit("NOT_CATEGORIZED"))
        dataFrame.withColumn("mdp_idregl", lit("-1"))
        dataFrame.withColumn("usedRef", lit(""))
      }
      i += 1
    }

    dataFrame
  }


dataFrame : "cdenjp", "cdguic", "numcpt", "mdp_codcat", "mdp_idregl" , mdp_codcat","mdp_idregl","usedRef"  if match add mdp_idregl, mdp_idregl,mdp_idregl with value bRef
```

Example - my dataframe :

```
val DF = Seq(("tt", "aa","bb"),("tt1", "aa1","bb2"),("tt1", "aa1","bb2")).toDF("t","a","b)
+---+---+---+---+
|  t|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
| tt| aa| bb| cc|
|tt1|aa1|bb2|cc3|
+---+---+---+---+
```

file.text content :

```
 ,aa,bb,cc
 ,aa1,bb2,cc3
tt4,aa4,bb4,cc4
tt1,aa1,,cc6


case class TOTO(a: String, b:String, c: String, d:String)


 val text = sc.textFile("file:///home/X176616/file")
 val bRef= textFromCsv.map(row => row.split(",", -1))
      .map(c => TOTO(c(0), c(1), c(2), c(3))).collect().sortBy(_.a)



def withMdpCodcat(bRef: Broadcast[Array[RefRglSDC]])(dataFrame: DataFrame):DataFrame
 dataframe.withColumn("mdp_codcat_new", "NOT_FOUND")  //first init not found, change if while if match 

    var matchRule = false
    var i = 0

    while (i < bRef.value.size && !matchRule) {
      if ((bRef.value(i).a.isEmpty || bRef.value(i).a.equals(signe))
        && (bRef.value(i).b.isEmpty || Lib.matchCdopcz(col(b), bRef.value(i).b))
        && (bRef.value(i).c.isEmpty || Lib.matchRule(col(c), bRef.value(i).c))
        )) {
        matchRule = true
        dataframe.withColumn("mdp_codcat_new", bRef.value(i).d)
        dataframe.withColumn("mdp_mdp_idregl_new" = bRef.value(i).e
       
      }
      i += 1
    }
```

Finally df if condition true

```
bRef.value(i).a.isEmpty || bRef.value(i).a.equals(signe))
            && (bRef.value(i).b.isEmpty || Lib.matchCdopcz(b.substring(1).toInt.toString, bRef.value(i).b))
            && (bRef.value(i).c.isEmpty || Lib.matchRule(c, bRef.value(i).c)

+---+---+---+---+-----------+----------+
|  t|  a|  b|  c|mdp_codcat |mdp_idregl|
+---+---+---+---+-----------|----------+
| tt| aa| bb| cc|cc         | other    |
| ab|aa1|bb2|cc3|cc4        | toto     | from bRef if true in while
| cd|aa1|bb2|cc3|cc4        | titi     |
|  b|a1 |b2 |c3 |NO_FOUND   |NO_FOUND  | (not_found if conditional false)
+---+---+---+---+----------------------+
+---+---+---+---+----------------------+
```

Comment: I need help please, thank you in advance

Comment: do your column names always be the same? these three names?, use an udf to update the fields value

Comment: You should write what you want to achieve and provide a simple example of input and output. There is not a reason to use while to loop in to a dataframe in an environment like spark

Comment: Tks the columns name is different ex colomns in dataFrame : "cdenjp", "cdguic", "numcpt", "mdp_codcat", "mdp_idregl" , mdp_codcat","mdp_idregl","usedRef"

Comment: Tks,  the columns name is different ex colomns in dataFrame : "cdenjp", "cdguic", "numcpt", "mdp_codcat", "mdp_idregl" ,   if match just 3 columns add with new value mdp_codcat","mdp_idregl","usedRef" else add 3 columns with other value

Answer (score 2):

You can not create a dataframe schema depending on a runtime value. I would try to do it simpler. First I´d create the three columns with a default value:

```
dataFrame.withColumn("mdp_codcat", lit(""))
dataFrame.withColumn("mdp_idregl", lit(""))
dataFrame.withColumn("usedRef", lit(""))
```

Then you can use a udf with your broadcasted value:

```
def mdp_codcat(bRef: Broadcast[Array[RefRglSDC]]) = udf { (field: String) =>
{
      // Your while and if stuff
      // return your update data
}}
```

And apply each udf to each field:

```
dataframe.withColumn("mdp_codcat_new", mdp_codcat(bRef)("mdp_codcat"))
```

Maybe it can help

Comment: tks for answer @EmiCareOfCell44, i add new details with exemple